# How do I link several elements of different types to one another in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, composite-key

I have Events, Documents, and Surveys which all need to be able to link to one another, I was planning on having a linking table with four columns as follows:

```
link_elements{
  element1_type CHAR(1)
  element1_id INTEGER
  element2_type CHAR(1)
  element2_id INTEGER
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to make the model in RoR so that I can use the element type field to identify which table the corresponding element id belongs to (Documents, Events, or Surveys).  I'm really new to Ruby and any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: How are these three models linked? Is there a User model? Can you explain how they are linked to one another? E.g: Event can have  a document and survey OR Document can have a Event and Survey etc. From your description it is not possible to discern your requirement.

Comment: I need to be able to link any type of element (document, event, or survey) to many of any other type of element.  So one document might link to two events and three surveys while a survey might link to two events and four documents and an event might link to two documents and 12 surveys.

Comment: A sample entry in this table might look like this:

      {'document','12','survey','24'}
      {'document','12','event','12'}

This in theory would link a document with id 12 to a survey with id 24 and that same document with an event that has an id of 12. My guess is that I would need to use a has_many: through: relationship but I can't figure out how to create the model to discriminate type using the first and third columns in the table.

Comment: I think what I need is polymorphic associations as described by this site in section 2.9 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, the question is can I have two sets of polymorphic data in one entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking for the `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations.

If you have an Event model, a Document model, and a Survey model, then you can specify in their respective .rb files in the Models folder if they have or belong to the other models.

Ex:  you want Surveys to belong to Documents.  In Survey.rb, add the line `belongs_to :document`.  In Document.rb, add the line `has_many :surveys`.

Now if you add a new "document_id" column in the Surveys table, it will look for a a Document object that corresponds to the id integer in that column.

For more info check out the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Documents are stored in one table, surveys in one table, and events in yet another table.  Simply adding a column to those tables would only allow me to link each element to only one other element of each type.  I need to figure out how to create a table that would let me link those elements together like the one I mentioned in the original posting of the question and get Ruby to read the first column as the table identifier and the second column as the row identifier.

Comment: Ah okay. Then you need a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.  This associations looks for a join table that has the ids of both the objects you are associating. I haven't personally used it, so I can't give you specifics, but look here(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and scroll down to the Many-to-many section. you can see what the join table looks like here(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001836). I'm guessing you'll need 3 separate join tables: Document-Survey, Document-Event, and Event-Survey.